# Selectively displaying text or a number in a result

Tags: sql, db2

I create sql like as below and when I try execute the sql the "MONTH" column become empty. It should display JAN for CPPERI = 1 but if I change JAN to number then the "MONTH" column will display the number 
Kindly help on this matter. Thank you

```
select EGAIT1 as "ACCOUNT NO" ,EATX15 as "DESC",CPYEA4 as "YEAR",
(case when CPPERI = 1 then  'JAN' else 0 end) as "MONTH",
sum(EGCUAM)as "AMT",EGAIT2 as "DEPARTMENT" from FGLEDG
INNER JOIN FCHACC on (EGCONO=EACONO and EGDIVI=EADIVI and EGAIT1 = EAAITM)
INNER JOIN CSYPER on (EGCONO=CPCONO and CPDIVI='TOH' and EGACDT between CPFDAT and CPTDAT)
where EGACDT between '20170101' and '20170131'
and EGAIT1 in ('56010','56020','56030','56040','56050')
and EGAIT2 in  ('AH03' ,'AH04' )
group by EGAIT1,EATX15,CPYEA4,CPPERI,CPTX15,EGAIT2
order by EGAIT1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both outcomes in case statement have to return same data type .In your case 'when' part returns varchar and else part integer. try something like this

```
 case when CPPERI = 1 then  'JAN' else '0' end
```